# Equations involving the Euler's totient function and Mersenne primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function, perfect-numbers, mersenne-numbers

In this post we denote the Euler's totient function as $\varphi(n)$, first we show a claim related to Mersenne primes, see for example this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime) and secondly we are going to ask a related conjecture.

We denote as $m=2^p-1$ a Mersenne prime, and we assume that there exists $k\geq 1$ an integer satisfying that $M=2^{p+2k}-1$, whenever $m<M$ are distinct Mersenne primes. With these definitions it is possible to prove the following claim.

**Claim.** If $m$ is a Mersenne prime and $1\leq k$ is an integer such that $2^{2k}m+2^{2k}-1$ is also a Mersenne prime, then the pair $(m,k)$ is a solution of the equation

$$(m^2-1)\left((2^{2k}m+2^{2k}-1)^2-1\right)=16\varphi\left(m(2^{2k}m+2^{2k}-1)\right)\varphi(\frac{m+1}{2})\varphi\left((m+1)2^{2k-1}\right).$$

> **Question.** Prove or refute, showing a counterexample, the following conjecture:
>
> *Let* $1\leq z$ *an integer, and* $1\leq\kappa$ *also integer satisfying* 
>   $$(z^2-1)\left((2^{2\kappa}z+2^{2\kappa}-1)^2-1\right)=16\varphi\left(z(2^{2\kappa}z+2^{2\kappa}-1)\right)\varphi(\frac{z+1}{2})\varphi\left((z+1)2^{2\kappa-1}\right).$$ 
>   *Then* $z$ *is a Mersenne prime, and* $2^{2\kappa}z+2^{2\kappa}-1$ *is also a Mersenne prime.*
>
> **Many thanks.**

Comment: How far have you checked your conjecture?

Comment: Many thanks for your attention and help @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris , for example using Sage Cell Server I can to check it for $1\leq z\leq 10^4$ and $1\leq \kappa\leq  20$ (I accept of course that this $\kappa$ is very small as computational evidence). The code that I've used is this line written in Pari-GP 
`for (z = 1, 10000,for (k = 1, 20, if (z%2==1&&(z^2-1)*((2^(2*k)*z+2^(2*k)-1)^2-1)==16*eulerphi((z+1)/2)*eulerphi((z+1)*2^(2*k-1))*eulerphi(z*(2^(2*k)*z+2^(2*k)-1)), print(z))))`

Comment: I did run your Pari-GP code using Sage Cell Server, @user243301.  However, they may have been some issues, as the green window was still there, and there was no output.  I also tried using a different browser, still no go.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris I did run it now, and it works, try to run the same code but put different upper limits for $z$ and/or $k$. That is an upper limit less than `10000` for $z$ or an upper limit less than `20` for $k$. Thus in my compute previous code works, on the other hand when the upper limits are very big Sage Cell Server send you the warning *PARI/GP interpreter crashed -- automatically restarting* in the green window.

Comment: Which language do I select?  GP?

Comment: Strange.  I am trying to run the code now with $1 \leq z \leq {10}^3$ and $1 \leq \kappa \leq 15$ and it is still thinking.

Comment: Then I don't know, it is required that the code is written in the same line, without break lines @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris Also you can copy&paste previous code from my profile (Activity>all actions>comments) instead of previous comment. Also sometimes in programming one types some special hidden character from the keyboard and maybe this produces errors.

Comment: This is really strange.  I tried running your code again, and now it works!
7
7
7
7
7
7
31
31
31
31
31
127
127
127
127
8191
8191
8191
Any idea why it appears to skip $3$?

Comment: Now I don't remember my calculations @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris I should run again my code.